# Faker object doesn't always seem to be populated when generating models from factories

Tags: ember-cli-mirage

https://ember-twiddle.com/e9d2be366d42ef411edc87c04825fa56?openFiles=mirage.factories.user.js%2C

why doesn't faker.image.imageURL() work here? (open debug to see it falling over of course). This isn't the only one of these I've seen periodically fail. Sometimes when I set a breakpoint in my mirage setup and inspect the faker object these things will be defined and sometimes they're not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's just a typo, you're typing `imageURL` instead of `imageUrl`.

Comment: [Corrected Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/b3ad7cac5e29e2a13a5ff5bdce5e8205?openFiles=mirage.factories.user.js%2C)